# Selenium webdriver - how to simulate Ctrl + Shift + v and add text in textarea

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Could someone help to solve the following:
 - I have to simulate in Selenium Webdriver (java), pressing

```
Ctrl + Shift + v
```

- and also input of some 6,7 sentences in text area (around 50 words).

Could not find solution on Stack neither could figure out how to achieve this action.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try: `webElement.SendKeys(Keys.Control+Keys.Shift+'v');`
or use class Robot http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

before you paste text on text area you should simulate left mouse click on this 
text area.

Comment: Thank you, but you did not notice that I have to add 50 words in textarea - which sendKeys to use and how?
Or any other command which will simulate keyboard and paste large text?

Comment: I am not sending 'v', but want to simulate Ctrl + Shift + v (Paste Special)

Comment: I think you should try answer @optimist_creeper. Do you copy this text before sending? because 'v' is not text you paste. 'v' simulates 'v' key on keyboard

Comment: Following are steps which I think should be done, but somewhere I am wrong and it doesn't work:
'driver.findElement ... (to find textarea). sendkeys (to simulate Ctrl + Shift + v)'
and now I need to copy (sendKeys again) with actual text
Not found the way

Comment: Zorane, if you are trying to simulate pasting that way then you should simulate copying this text it in the same way. I'm not sure how did you imagine to accomplish this with combination of paste and sendKeys().

Comment: @acikojevic Simply, I am confused how to solve this - not trying to achieve or to imagine anything - just asking for help

Comment: Ok. For example you have some web element with text you should paste to other place(your text area). Ok. Find web element with text (for example it will be textElement). Then you should copy this text for paste in the future. `textElement.SendKeys(Keys.Control+'c')`. You copied your text. Then you should paste your text. E.g. you have web element textArea. `textArea.SendKeys(Keys.Control+'v')` (or Keys.Control+Keys.Shift+'v'  if you use custom hotkeys). I don't understand in what problem is. May be you explain your task more detailed to pass our misunderstanding.

Comment: @eva.eis Now, I see where confused you guys. Namely, i have predefined text (those 50 words) - it is i.e one Notepad file with 50 words.
In summary, what I am trying to achieve is to in text area put those 50 words 
I found that send.Keys is very slow for those kind of input. 
So, I do not have to find any text and copy it into clipboard, just do the input into text area (but since that app is done that way - forbidden Copy - Paste and only way to Paste some text is with Ctrl + Shift + v - 'Paste Special' - is it possible to achieve just with send.Keys by typing those 50 words?

Answer (score 0):

Use the code snippets below:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SHIFT, "v")).build().perform();
```

Comment: Where and how to put actual text - 'v' is not text but part of keyboard combination - another sendKeys or what?

Comment: Not getting what to do

Answer (score 0):

You can input data by javascript executor instead of paste content.I jst share my idea with you..

```
element=objWebDriver.findElement(By.xpath("Your xpath"));
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1]);",element,"some value);
```

You get the description using XPath and assign it to the element.And input data by javascript executor

You can see more information about javascript executor [Click Here](https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html)